# jQuery append multiple Elements

Tags: jquery

I have multiple Divs with an H1-Tag inside. Like this:

```
     <div id="home">
<div class="link-container">
        <h1>headline</h1> 
        <div class="image-inner">
            <img src="img.jpg" width="300" height="380" alt="">
        </div>
        <p>Evel et rest, volesequos quo venditem labore cone&nbsp;repelia voluptatat reidertum.</p>
        <div class="content-inner"></div>
    </div>
        <div class="link-container">
        <h1>headline</h1> 
        <div class="image-inner">
            <img src="img.jpg" width="300" height="380" alt="">
        </div>
        <p>Evel et rest, volesequos quo venditem labore cone&nbsp;repelia voluptatat reidertum.</p>
        <div class="content-inner"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The Problem is, that i want the H1-Tag inside the content-inner Div. But how?
With this Code, i have all H1-Tags in the first Div.

```
$("#home h1").appendTo(".content-inner");
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use:

```
$('#home div.link-container').each(function () {
    $(this).find('h1').appendTo($(this).find('div.content-inner'))
})
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/7jhx67Lm/)**